# ruby gem hashdiff - how to upgrade to 1.0 to stop deprecation warnings

Tags: ruby, rubygems

The gem [`hashdiff`](https://github.com/liufengyun/hashdiff) has problems with another gem using the same namespace, it gives the deprecation warning:

*The HashDiff constant used by this gem conflicts with another gem of a similar name.  As of version 1.0 the HashDiff constant will be completely removed and replaced by Hashdiff.  For more information see https://github.com/liufengyun/hashdiff/issues/45.*

(The link is to a long conversation, even reading it I am not sure how to upgrade this particular gem)

My `/Gemfile` does not have hashdiff in, however there is a gem which depends on it, in `/Gemfile.lock` there is `hashdiff (0.4.0)`.

To force hashdiff to upgrade to 1.0, I added `gem 'hashdiff', '~> 1.0'` to  `/Gemfile` and ran `bundle update hashdiff` but:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Could not find gem 'hashdiff (~> 1.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Alas rubygems does not have version 1.0.

How are we people dealing with the deprecation warning? Ignoring it until the gem becomes available? Or something else?

Comment: What is the gem having `hashdiff` as dependency ?

Comment: `webmock (3.6.0)`. There's 41 million downloads of hashdiff and currently no mention of how to upgrade to 1.0 on the official github page, so I was hoping to keep the question generic ^'_^

Comment: Hashdiff is still in beta, one workaround would be to use the beta from GitHub in your Gemfile, next webmock:  `gem "hashdiff", github: "liufengyun/hashdiff", ref: "v1.0.0.beta1"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bundler doesn't consider beta versions of a gem when solving dependencies unless you explicitly tell bundler to use such a beta version.

I would just add that gem together with a comment to my Gemfile

```
# FIXME: Force bundler to use the beta version of the hashdiff gem
#        `hashdiff` is a dependency of the `webmock` gem. Feel free to remove
#        the following line from this Gemfile as soon as hashdiff 1.0.0 is
#        officially released.
gem 'hashdiff', '>= 1.0.0.beta1' 
gem 'webmock'
```

and then run `bundle update hashdiff`.

**Update**

Version `1.0.0` of the `hashdiff` gem was released on 2019-07-15. Therefore this workaround is not needed anymore and a `bundle update hashdiff` – without the need to update the `Gemfile` first – should solve the issue.